# Como manejar el tema de Hilos en Python 3.6

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada con Python y Tkinter y me gustaría saber algo mas acerca de los hilos de ejecución. Por el momento, como necesito cargar un dataframe bastante grande al inicio de la aplicación, uso la libreria "threading":

```
t = threading.Thread(target=cargar_dataframe, args=("fichero.xlsx",))
t.start()

def cargar_dataframe(filename):
    global df_global
    file = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df_global = pd.DataFrame(file)
    print("dataframe CARGADO!!!")
```

Ahora que he avanzado mas en la aplicacion, tengo algunas tareas que no tardan tanto como esta pero que me la dejan 'colgada' durante algunos segundos y he pensado que quiza siguiente ese metodo puedo hacer que otros hilos que no sean el principal realicen estas tareas. Mis preguntas son:

¿Está bien pensado?
¿Esa librería es la correcta o hay alguna otra mas orientada a lo que busco?
Si cuando hago clic en un botón, tengo que llamar a una función, y que esta realice la creación de un hilo y la posterior llamada a otra función para que la ejecute ese hilo se hace un poco farragoso.

A ver si alguien que controle del tema me puede dar unas indicaciones básicas.

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo bien el comentario de que el hilo se hace *"farragoso"*. ¿Cuántos botones tienes y qué hacen cada uno? Completa la pregunta y especifica qué usas (supongo que `pd` será `pandas`, ¿no?). De todos modos, no entiendo qué ganancia en velocidad quieres conseguir si está claro que no vas a poder hacer gran cosa hasta que esté cargado el dataframe.

Comment: Lo de que es farragoso no me refiero al hilo, si no al tema de llamar a una función como evento de un botón y desde esa función llamar a otra generando un hilo nuevo t = threading.Thread(target=cargar_dataframe, args=("fichero.xlsx",))
t.start(). No se si es correcto o se puede hacer de otra forma. Pd es pandas. Quiero conseguir que estando abierta la aplicación, si hago alguna acción en otro hilo, no me la bloquee, pareciendo que se ha quedado colgada.

Comment: En temas de concurrencia no existen soluciones que sirvan para todo. Además python (CPython) tiene el bloqueo GIL que impide que varios hilos compartan simultánemente el mismo intérprete de python (de ahí los bloqueos). Si tienes suerte, pandas usará alguna librería nativa no-python para cargar el fichero en un hilo aparte del principal. Mejor que usar usar multihilo, prueba con multiproceso (módulo [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)). Lamentablemente, es un tema demasiado amplio para ser tratado en este foro.